# Unknown variable column size in vector

Tags: c++, variables, vector, visual-studio-2013, ifstream

My first question on this site. Plus rather new to C++.

I've been looking for a way to fill in a vector from a text file. However, the column size of each row is different and unknown beforehand.

Let me show you an example, this is the text file I would like to get in the vector:

```
3

1 1

1 2

0
```

(Meaning of table: there are 3 activities within project x, the first activity has 1 direct predecessor (activity 1), the second activity also has one direct predecessor (activity 2) and finally the last activity has no predecessors.)

I want this textfile in a vector, however I have several similar textfiles, with different number of columns that I need to read in.

Since I know the amount of activities within each project, I am able to define the number of rows. However, I do not know the number of columns...

What I've tried now is to work with inFile.good(), to see if I've reached the end of the textfile. However, I need something to see if I am at the end of the row. The code I already have is:

```
    //READING NUMBER OF ACTIVITIES

inFile >> nbr_activities;
cout <<  nbr_activities << endl;

//READING PRECEDENCE RELATIONSHIP
for (int i = 0; i < nbr_activities; i++)
{

    vector<int> temp_vec;
    while (inFile.good())
    {
        int skills;
        inFile >> skills;
        temp_vec.push_back(skills);
    }
    precedence_per_activity.push_back(temp_vec);
}

//PRINTING THE VECTOR
for (int i = 0; i < nbr_activities; i++)
{
    int j = 0;
    while (inFile.good())
    {
        j++;
        cout << precedence_per_activity[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

However, this does not give a good outcome.

Could anyone help me please? I really cannot see any solution..

Comment: `while (inFile.good())` this should be `while (inFile >> skills)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `precedence_per_activity` is defined to be:

```
vector<vector<int>> precedence_per_activity;
```

so to print you want something like:

```
for (auto v : precedence_per_activity) {
   for (auto i : v) {
        cout << i << ' ';
   }
   cout << endl;
 }
```

Comment: True, this + my answer should fix it.

Comment: Don't I need to declare the 'v' and 'i' here? Because that is the error C++ now gives...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
//READING PRECEDENCE RELATIONSHIP
for (int i = 0; i < nbr_activities; i++)
{

    vector<int> temp_vec;
    while (inFile.good()) // READ FULL FILE
    {
        int skills;
        inFile >> skills;
        temp_vec.push_back(skills);
    }
    precedence_per_activity.push_back(temp_vec);
}
```

For every line, you shouldn't read full file. You need take first number and do another for:

```
//READING PRECEDENCE RELATIONSHIP
for (int i = 0; i < nbr_activities; i++)
{
    int counter;
    vector<int> temp_vec;
    inFile>>counter;
    for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++)
    {
        int skills;
        inFile >> skills;
        temp_vec.push_back(skills);
    }
    precedence_per_activity.push_back(temp_vec);
}
```